# Which historical Unixes supported terminal I/O with five or six bits per character, and with what character sets?

Tags: history, unix, terminal, serial

[The specification for `termios.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/termios.h.html#tag_13_72_03_05) includes a facility for controlling the number of bits per character sent over the serial line, the CSIZE and CSn constants.  You can request five, six, seven, or eight bits per character.

Nowadays, of course, five- and six-bit-per-character serial protocols are thoroughly obsolete.  It seems logical that there must have, historically, been Unixes that *did* implement five- or six-bit terminal I/O, because the constants wouldn't exist if not, but I've browsed through the serial drivers of contemporary, Linux and FreeBSD and I have the impression that most of them either ignore or refuse a request to put a serial line into five- or six-bit mode.  (Every driver has its own implementation of `tcsetattr`, which makes it extremely tedious to try to find out if *any* driver still supports these modes.) Coming at it from the other end, the Teletype Model 33 was already a seven-bit terminal in 1963, and all the references I can find for five- and six-bit codes still in use in the 1970s make them sound like they were only used for special purposes and not for general serial communication.

Furthermore, the `termios` interface doesn't give you any way to specify what character encoding to use in five- or six-bit mode, despite the many competing standards and the apparent necessity of translating from ASCII, so I'm guessing this *isn't* a case of "we have one computer and several hundred terminals of various models -- make it work with all of them", as the story goes re the development of the higher-level termcap/terminfo system.

So, the question is, what historical implementations of Unix *did* implement five- and/or six-bit terminal I/O, for use with what peripherals, and which character encodings?

Comment: Many old teletypes (not the Model 33 ASR; it was *the first* ASCII teletype) were 5-bit.  Thus, I'd bet it was added the first time someone at Bell needed to use an *old* tty (which weren't that old in the early 1970s).

Comment: https://ia800606.us.archive.org/17/items/enf-ascii/ascii.pdf has interesting info that may be useful.

Comment: And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletype_Corporation lists various models. Baudot varieties were around for some time, even if only as printers.

Comment: The chain of thought may be a bit longer. The drivers have support for UART features, and UARTs commonly have had support for 5 to 8 bit frames, and UARTs were designed support those values to either be compatible with existing equipment, or allow making new equipment that use 5 bit frames.

Comment: Someone actually got [a Baudot-code Teletype to work on Linux](https://hackaday.com/2020/04/15/logging-into-linux-with-a-1930s-teletype/), though it required a bunch of custom hacking.

Comment: If you look at early 1970s line interfaces for the PDP-11, they mostly come with programmable support for 5, 6, 7, 8 bit frames.  So I suspect that it was less a matter of 'what terminals do we have' than 'what line cards do we support'.

Comment: Even the 8250 in the IBM PC still [supported](https://web.archive.org/web/20160503070506/http://archive.pcjs.org/pubs/pc/datasheets/8250A-UART.pdf) 5, 6, 7 and 8 bit per character. The Super-I/O chip on the mainboard of the PC I am writing this on still does. I'll guess I need to try out it if I can put it into that mode under Linux...

Answer (score 6):

They were supported by Unix System III with the DH11 and DZ11 asynchronous multiplexers (serial line interfaces for DEC systems).

While `termios.h` is only in POSIX systems, the constants come from the similarly-named `termio.h` in the AT&T operating system.  The [DH11 driver](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=SysIII/usr/src/uts/pdp11/io/dh.c) passes the bits to the register like so (the [DZ11 driver](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=SysIII/usr/src/uts/vax/io/dz.c) is mostly the same):

```
    lpr = (flags&CBAUD)<<10;
    if (flags&CREAD)
        lpr |= (flags&CBAUD)<<6;
    if (flags&CS6)
        lpr |= BITS6;
    if (flags&CS7)
        lpr |= BITS7;
    if (flags&PARENB) {
        lpr |= PENABLE;
        if (flags&PARODD)
            lpr |= OPAR;
    }
    if (flags&CSTOPB)
        lpr |= TWOSB;
```

Note that `termio.h` defines the size constants like so:

```
#define CSIZE   0000060
#define CS5 0
#define CS6 0000020
#define CS7 0000040
#define CS8 0000060
```

It doesn't seem that this affects anything other than what is passed to the register for the particular serial line.

Answer (score 4):

While many types of peripheral assumed fewer than 7-bits per character (i.e. did not support 7-bit ASCII), I think it's important to appreciate that just because termios supports a setting doesn't mean that it's intended for an interactive shell session.

So even today you would use termios to set up a non-standard (e.g. six-bit 110-BPS) connection to /dev/ttyUSB0 talking to an Arduino outputting nothing but numbers to a display device.